# How to ssh into openshift app using the 'rhc' command on windows?

Tags: windows, openshift, putty, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to ssh (from windows) into my Openshift app using the 'rhc' command

```
rhc app-ssh <app name>
```

I have followed the Openshift instruction here:

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-rhc-app-ssh-command

Putty is returning the error "Putty Command Line Error: unknown option "-V" and then fails.  My google searches indicate putty has a "-v" (lowercase) option for turning on Verbose.  I'm not sure if it's one in the same.

If I use the Putty GUI everything works fine.  I would like to figure out how to ssh into my openshift app using the command line.

How do I ssh into my openshift app using the 'rhc' command on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in RHC for windows. They fixed it in a forked version.

[Bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1149016)

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to generate private and public key. You can use puttygen to do that.
- Then you should import public key into your OpenShift account.
- And then use private key with putty.

Here is detailed [instruction with illustrations](https://druss.co/2015/01/how-to-connect-to-openshift-with-putty-ssh/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the rhc setup command first to see if everything is configured correctly?

Comment: RHC setup was run and reported back everything was configured.  I got the same error when I tried 'rhc app-ssh <app-name>.  Putty is not liking the command line arguments that rhc is sending to it.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
rhc ssh appname
```

Worked fine for me