# cannot find ssh executable

Tags: git, github, ssh, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to acces the logs of my openshift application and the way to do that is with an ssh command that goes like `rhc ssh ...` . I have the rhc client tools but apparently no ssh executable. I looked around in this website and people give the location of the ssh executable under the git folder. But I don't have those because I installed github for windows (apprently there is a difference).

Comment: For windows environment, Install git client tools to have ssh http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: So github doesn't have it?

Comment: I think it should, but I haven't used Github tools

Comment: may be this will help you: [ssh into openshift app using the 'rhc' command on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25491464/4381432)